# Visual Studio Code - Where is the terminal output history saved?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I ran a python script that had important timings inside the script but I accidently killed the terminal.
Is there a way to see terminal history outputs somewhere?

I tried to find an answer to my question but only thing I could find is how to find the history of commands I have ran.